# Two Rosemary Bushes Growing Together (Well) For Years: Then One Died

Tags: rosemary

I have had a rosemary plant growing in my back yard for years, and the thing has been an absolute beast, quadrupling in size even though I put in no effort to keep it healthy.  It does get watered by a sprinkler, and I often trim it back because it grows so much ... but that's it.

[image]

Relatively recently though one of the plants (apparently it split itself at some point) has turned white and dried out.  Meanwhile, the plant next to (and sort of interwoven with) it is doing perfectly fine: all the leaves are green and it looks healthy.

Does anyone know what has happened?  If it's a fungus or disease, I assume I should clear the dead plant, but if it's anything else, that would probably make things worse rather than better ... right?

Comment: IMPE, (well, mine can't be outside through winter here, so they are potted) they eventually "just die", so rooting the occasional cutting to have new plants is advisable.

Comment: In the UK at least, Rosemary will grow into very sizeable bushes from nodes growing up from the roots and without any input from you. The only thing you need to do is prune away any dead shoots which are symptomatic of nothing but old age. 

It can help the plant to prune away living stems too to yield rosemary for the kitchen as well as ensure that overcrowded stems are removed to ensure there is enough air movement around each stem to avoid mildew etc.  

Those removed cuttings can of course be rooted in sand and left outdoors or in a cold greenhouse.